# Python exception hook returning wrong function

Tags: python, exception

I want to customize Python exception format for easier searching in logs. For uncaught exceptions I think I should use an exception hook, so I did this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="[%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
)

def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    logging.error(
        "",
        exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    )

sys.excepthook = exception_hook
```

So I have file name, function name and line number nicely formatted, in addition to the message with traceback. For `INFO` level this works. However, for exceptions I get:

```
[ERROR] [setup_logging.py.exception_hook:13] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/PycharmProjects/data_processing/lib/utils/tmp.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise ValueError("this is an exception")
ValueError: this is an exception
```

This is for simple `raise ValueError("this is an exception")`. As you can see, I get the file name, function name and line number from exception hook, rather than from the original exception.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this is the `stacklevel` keyword argument. As described in the docs for [`logger.debug`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug):

> The third optional keyword argument is `stacklevel`, which defaults to `1`. If greater than 1, the corresponding number of stack frames are skipped when computing the line number and function name set in the `LogRecord` created for the logging event. This can be used in logging helpers so that the function name, filename and line number recorded are not the information for the helper function/method, but rather its caller. The name of this parameter mirrors the equivalent one in the `warnings` module.

Try changing your `exception_hook` to:

```
def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    logging.exception(
        "",
        exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback),
        stacklevel=2,
    )
```

(I also changed `logging.error` to `logging.exception`, as I believe that is more appropriate to use in an exception handler.)

Comment: I see why this should work, but for some reason it does not. I still get the same result.